# ¿Cómo convierto un elemento de una lista de String a Int?

Tags: kotlin

Estoy haciendo una calculadora en kotlin, y estoy haciendo una lista con un split que separe por el signo más, pero a la hora de recorrer la lista para hacer la suma, me sale el error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

```
 fun sumar(){
            val etNumero = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etNumero)
            val tvPendiente = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvPendiente)
            var list = etNumero.text.split("+")
            if(tvPendiente.text.isEmpty()){
                tvPendiente.setText((list[0].toString().toInt()+0).toString())
            }else{
                var limite = 1..list.size
                var acum: Int = 0
                for(num in limite){
                    acum = acum +list.get(num-1).toInt()
                    
                }

                
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué quieres saber exactamente? Ya sabes que la conversión se hace con el método `toInt()`. El error es porque la string `""` no se puede convertir a `Int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso ocurre porque llega a la expresión del tipo:

```
"".toInt()
```

Una mejor solución puede ser usar `mapNotNull` junto con `toIntOrNull`:

```
val expr = "12+14+"
val list = expr.split("+") // ['12', '14', '']
val result = list.mapNotNull { it.toIntOrNull() }.sum() // 26
println(result)
```

Las listas en Kotlin tienen:

- [`mapNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-not-null.html#mapnotnull), recibe una función y regresa todos los elementos que resultaron no ser nulos después de aplicar map, las siguientes expresines son equivalentes:

  ```
  list.mapNotNull { ... }
  list.map { ... }.filter { it != null }
  ```
- [`toIntOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int-or-null.html#tointornull) parte de un string y revisa si se puede transformar a un entero y lo regresa en caso de éxito, en otro caso regresa null.
- [`sum`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum.html#sum) Simplemente regresa el resultado de haber sumado todos los elementos de la colección.

[image: Kotlin]

Comment: Te agradezco muchisimo la explicación, si funcionó.

Comment: Puedes marcar tu pregunta como resulta para que pueda ser de ayuda para otros usuarios :)